# How to select checked boxes names when clicking button in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, checkbox

Action ADD CLICK on my button $Tab1BTNCreation:  I want to copy a folder including some subfolders (mentioned by checked checkboxes) to a certain destination. The selected checkboxes indicates exactly which folder to copy. I've tried a lot of options but nothing is working at that point.  The concerned variables are $Checkboxes and $CheckboxesNames in TAB1. I've gave names to my checkboxes variables so the '-unclude' parameter can recognize the folder name...   Scroll down till '///// HERE //// Bouton Creation  /////////'
Thank you for your help.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass 
Add-type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms 

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="Programme de tests QA" Height="515" Width="828" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="825">

            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Tab1"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        Margin="10,2"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#292929" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF23BBB8" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
           
            <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="CR`ÉATION" Height="40" Width="273" Background="#292929" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Foreground="white" IsSelected="True">
                <Grid Background="#292929" Width="840" Height="455" Margin="-7,1,-14,-4">
                    <Label x:Name="titre1" Content="cr`éation d'une nouvelle serie" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Foreground="#797979" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="49,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="723"/>
                    <Line X1="55" X2="440" Y1="99" Y2="99" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="55" X2="440" Y1="200" Y2="200" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="99" Y2="99" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="200" Y2="200" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="60,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="de" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="60,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="vers" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBdeRep1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="107,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" BorderBrush="#FF23BBB8" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBdeSerie1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="227,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" BorderBrush="#FF23BBB8" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBversRep1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="107,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" BorderBrush="#FF23BBB8" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TBversSerie1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="227,159,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" Padding="2" MaxLength="33" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                     
                     <Grid x:Name="CheckBoxGroup1">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBbin1" Content=" bin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBexport1" Content=" export" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBparam1" Content=" param" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBlist1" Content=" list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="600,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBscript1" Content=" script" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="600,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBtemplate1" Content=" template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="600,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    </Grid>
                   
                    <Button x:Name="BTNcreation" Content="cr`éer la s`érie et synchroniser" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="480,335,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="white" Background="#FF23BBB8" Width="290"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TBmessages1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="55,238,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="Affichage des messages d'erreurs." Foreground="#797979" Padding="6" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="383"/>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>



            <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="SYNCHRONISATION" Background="#FF00565F" Height="40" Width="273" BorderBrush="#FF00565F" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold">
                <Grid Background="#292929" Width="840" Height="455" Margin="-7,1,-14,-4">
                    <Label Content="synchronisation d'une s`érie" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Foreground="#797979" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="49,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="723"/>
                    <Line X1="55" X2="440" Y1="200" Y2="200" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="55" X2="440" Y1="99" Y2="99" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="99" Y2="99" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="200" Y2="200" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="60,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="de" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="60,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="vers" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Foreground="#797979"/>


                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBdeRep2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="107,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBdeSerie2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="227,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBversRep2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="107,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBversSerie2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="227,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBbin2" Content=" bin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBexport2" Content=" export" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBparam2" Content=" param" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBlist2" Content=" list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="600,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBscript2" Content=" script" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="600,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBtemplate2" Content=" template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="600,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    
                    <TextBox x:Name="TBmessages2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="55,238,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="Affichage des messages d'erreurs." Foreground="#797979" Padding="6" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="383"/>
                    <Button x:Name="BTNsynchro" Content="synchroniser la s`érie" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="480,335,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="white" Background="#FF23BBB8" Width="290"/>

                </Grid>


            </TabItem>



            <TabItem x:Name="tab3" Header="EX`ÉCUTION"  Background="#FF00565F" Height="40" Width="273" BorderBrush="#FF00565F" FontSize="12" Foreground="white" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold">
                <Grid Background="#292929" Width="840" Height="455" Margin="-7,1,-14,-4"  >
                    <Label x:Name="titre3" Content="ex`écution des tests QA" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="20" Foreground="#797979" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="49,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="723"/>
                    <Line X1="55" X2="335" Y1="99" Y2="99" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="55" X2="335" Y1="160" Y2="160" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="99" Y2="99" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="250" Y2="250" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <Line X1="480" X2="770" Y1="200" Y2="200" Stroke="#5f5f5f" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="54,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="version" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="482,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="`équipe" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="482,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="liste" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Foreground="#797979"/>

                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBversion3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="113,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="TBbuild3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="201,120,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Build" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" Padding="2" MaxLength="4" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="TBrevision3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="297,120,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="R`év." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Padding="2" MaxLength="3" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBequipe3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="542,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" BorderBrush="#FF23BBB8" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979"/>        
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CBBliste3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="542,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" BorderBrush="#FF23BBB8" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="#797979"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CBrtf3" Content=" produire les fichiers en format .rtf" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="480,217,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230"  Foreground="#797979"/>

                    <TextBox x:Name="TBmessages3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" Margin="55,193,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Affichage des messages d'erreurs." Foreground="#797979" Padding="6" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="383"/>
                    <Button x:Name="BTNexecution" Content="lancer les tests" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="480,335,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="white" Background="#FF23BBB8" Width="290"/>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>


    </Grid>
</Window>

"@

#Read XAML (Parse it)
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

#region ----- xaml objects to variables -----

#Connect to Controls TAB2
$Tab1CBB1 = $Window.FindName('CBBdeRep1')
$Tab1CBB2 = $Window.FindName('CBBdeSerie1')
$Tab1CBB3 = $Window.FindName('CBBversRep1')
$Tab1TB4 = $Window.FindName('TBversSerie1')
($Tab1CBbin = $Window.FindName('CBbin1')).Name = 'Bin'
($Tab1CBexport = $Window.FindName('CBexport1')).Name = 'Export'
($Tab1CBparam = $Window.FindName('CBparam1')).Name = 'Param'
($Tab1CBlist = $Window.FindName('CBlist1')).Name = 'List'
($Tab1CBscript = $Window.FindName('CBscript1')).Name = 'QA\Script'
($Tab1CBtemplate = $Window.FindName('CBtemplate1')).Name = 'Template'
$Tab1TBmessages = $Window.findName("TBmessages1")
$Tab1BTNcreation = $Window.findName("BTNcreation")


#Connect to Controls TAB2
$Tab2CBB1 = $Window.FindName('CBBdeRep2')
$Tab2CBB2 = $Window.FindName('CBBdeSerie2')
$Tab2CBB3 = $Window.FindName('CBBversRep2')
$Tab2CBB4 = $Window.FindName('CBBversSerie2')
$Tab2CBbin = $Window.FindName('CBbin2')
$Tab2CBexport = $Window.FindName('CBbin2')
$Tab2CBparam = $Window.FindName('CBparam2')
$Tab2CBlist = $Window.FindName('CBlist2')
$Tab2CBscript = $Window.FindName('CBscript2')
$Tab2CBtemplate = $Window.FindName('CBtemplate2')
$Tab2TBmessages = $Window.findName("TBmessages2")
$Tab2BTNsynchro = $Window.findName("BTNsyncro")

#Connect to Controls TAB2
$Tab3CBBversion = $Window.findName("CBBVersion3")
$Tab3TBbuild = $Window.findName("TBbuild3")
$Tab3TBrev = $Window.findName("TBrevision3")
$Tab3CBBequipe = $Window.findName("CBBequipe3")
$Tab3CBBliste = $Window.findName("CBBliste3")
$Tab3CBrtf = $Window.findName("CBrtf3")
$Tab3TBmessages = $Window.findName("TBmessages3")
$Tab3BTNexecution = $Window.findName("BTNexecution")
#endregion

#region ---- Path variables  ----- 
$pathDE='E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation\DE\'
$pathVERS='E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation\VERS\'
$pathDBQcust01='E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation\DE\DBQcust01\Sets\' 
$pathQA14='E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation\DE\QA14\Sets\'
$pathQA15='E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation\DE\QA15\Sets\'
$pathSERIE = 'E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation\DE\QA14\Sets'  #simulation
$pathSIMULATION = 'E:\Scripts\BibliothequePowershell\Melanie\GUI-ProgTestQA\Simulation'
#endregion ----

#lists of series
$listQA14 = Get-ChildItem $pathQA14 -Directory -Name 
$listQA15 = Get-ChildItem $pathQA15 -Directory -Name 
$listDBQcust01 = Get-ChildItem $pathDBQcust01 -Directory -Name 
$FolderLists = Get-ChildItem $pathSIMULATION\Listes -Include *.txt -Name



#------------- TAB1 ------------------

#region /// ComboBox 1 : DE folder
$FoldersCBB1 = @('--- choisir ---','DBQcust01','QA14','QA15')
$Tab1CBB1.SelectedItem = '--- choisir ---'
foreach ($Folder in $FoldersCBB1) {
$Tab1CBB1.Items.Add($Folder)
}
#endregion



#region /// ComboBox 2 : DE SERIE    (éventuellement changer pour SWITCH)
$Tab1CBB1.add_SelectionChanged({
$Selection = ($Tab1CBB1.SelectedItem.ToString())

  if ($Selection -eq 'QA14') 
    { 
        $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear()
        $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add('--- choisir une série sous QA14 ---')
        $Tab1CBB2.SelectedItem = '--- choisir une série sous QA14 ---' 
        foreach ($Serie in $listQA14) {
            $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($Serie)
        }   
    }   
    
    elseif ($Selection -eq 'QA15') 
    {
            $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear()
            $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add('--- choisir une série sous QA15 ---')
            $Tab1CBB2.SelectedItem = '--- choisir une série sous QA15 ---'
            foreach ($Serie in $listQA15)  {
                $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($Serie)
            }
    }    
    
    elseif ($Selection -eq 'DBQcust01') 
    {
            $Tab1CBB2.Items.Clear()
            $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add('--- choisir une série sous DBQcust01 ---')
            $Tab1CBB2.SelectedItem = '--- choisir une série sous DBQcust01 ---'
            foreach ($Serie in $listDBQcust01) {
                 $Tab1CBB2.Items.Add($Serie)
            }
   }

})

#endregion




#region /// ComboBox 3 : VERS folder
$FoldersCBB3 = @('SPMT','OTHER')
$Tab1CBB3.Items.Add('--- choisir ---')
$Tab1CBB3.SelectedItem = '--- choisir ---' 
foreach ($Folder in $FoldersCBB3) {
    $Tab1CBB3.Items.Add($Folder)
}

#endregion




#region /// TextBox 4 : VERS Série 
#à venir (essayer de mettre le contenu des sélections des cbb automatiquement dans le textbox)

$Tab1TB4.text = "SÉRIE+ÉQUIPE"
#endregion




#region ///// HERE //// Bouton Creation  /////////

$Tab1BTNcreation.Add_Click({


    $SelectionCBB1 = ($Tab1CBB1.SelectedValue)
    $SelectionCBB2 = ($Tab1CBB2.SelectedValue)
    $SelectionCBB3 = ($Tab1CBB3.SelectedValue)
    $SelectionTB4 = ($Tab1TB4.Text)
    

    $CheckedBoxes = get-variable $Tab1CB* | Where-object {$_.IsChecked = $true}
    $CheckBoxesNames= $CheckedBoxes.Name


   New-item -ItemType Directory -Path "$pathVERS\$SelectionCBB3" -Name "$SelectionTB4"
   
   Copy-Item -Path "$pathDE\$SelectionCBB1\$SelectionCBB2" -include $CheckedBoxesNames -Recurse -Destination "$pathVERS\$SelectionCBB3\$SelectionTB4" 

})

#endregion






#------------- TAB2 ------------------

#------------- TAB3 ------------------






$Window.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: I normally use something along the lines of `if ($CBbin1.checked -eq $true){ do this} else { do this}`

Comment: Yeah, i've tried this as well. The issue here : When i use IF statement for each of them, when i click my button it checks automatically all the checkboxes even though i've checked just a couple of them. If i use the ELSEIF, it consideres only the IF one, so the first one here.... 

  New-item -ItemType Directory -Path "$pathVERS\$SelectionCBB3" -Name "$SelectionTB4"

   If ($Tab1CBbin.IsChecked = $true) { copy-item -Path "$pathDE\$SelectionCBB1\sets\$SelectionCBB2\Bin" -Recurse -Destination "$pathVERS\$SelectionCBB3\$SelectionTB4"  }
   ElseIf ($Tab1CBexport.IsChec...

Comment: `($Tab1CBbin.IsChecked = $true)` assigns the properties. It should be `($Tab1CBbin.IsChecked -eq $True)`. That said I would try to remove the `elseif`. Do not use `else`, Just `if`, break `if`, again, no `else`. Close that if statement with `else` at the end and leave it blank or comment out the line. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit that I found after going through this script.

Changes are below.

Your second line `Add-type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms` are for Windows Forms, not WPF. That should read

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework
```

You cannot mix and match here, it causes issues later on. If you want to use forms, then use forms. If you want to use WPF, then use WPF, do not mix them. :)

Delete lines 2-5 replacing line 2 with above.

On line 287

```
 $CheckedBoxes = get-variable $Tab1CB* | Where-object {$_.IsChecked = $true}
```

The `=` sign assigns a variable's "value" and does not do what `-eq` does, which is what you would want to use in this case as you are checking against data.

```
 $CheckedBoxes = get-variable $Tab1CB* | Where-object {$_.IsChecked -eq $true}
```

Comment: Oh gease ! Thank you so much ! The only problem was the = instead of -eq ! Thank you for taking the time to explain for the first lines about Forms - WPF, i'm still beginner in that stuff. Also, concerning the lines concerning the -Directory -Name, did you meant that it would be better to write -Include Directory -Name? I know it would seem more logical buti've tried that already and it was not working. But, the -Directory -Name was working. Thank you again !

Comment: You bet, we are all new at some point. I am by far no professional. Mostly trial and error. I have edited my answer to be more succinct and get to the root of the problem you were having. That said if -Include Directory -Name works run with it. I wasn't sure. Also removed from the answer as it was speculation.

Comment: You are very welcome. If this answered your question can you please mark it as correct? :)

Comment: Where do i see this option ?